# MPI parallel write to a TIFF file

Tags: mpi, tiff

I'm trying to write a TIFF file in MPI code. Different processors have different parts of the image, and I want to write the image to the file in parallel.

The write fails, only the 1st processor can write to it.

How do I do this?

There is no error in my implementation, just it does not work.
I used `h=TIFFOpen(file, "a+")` on each processor to open the same file (I am not sure whether this is a right way or not), then each processor who is responsible for a directory will write the header at its own place using `TIFFSetDirectory(h, directorynumber)`, then the content of each directory will be written. I will finalize with `TIFFWriteDirectory(h)`. The result would be the first directory which is written on the file.

I thought that I need to open the file using MPI_IO but doing this way it is not TIFFOpen?

Comment: What are you trying? What's the result? What's the error? We need a lot more information before we can help you.

Comment: Is there any open source solution for parallel libtiff. It is really hard to believe that nobody never tried to write a parallel IO for the tiff library.

Answer (score 2):

Different MPI tasks are independent programs, running on independent hosts from the OS point of view. In your case the TIFF library is not designed to handle parallel operations, so opening the file will lead the first process to succeed, all the rest to fail because they found the file already opened (on a shared filesystem).

Except in case you are dealing with *huge* images (eg: astronomical images) where it's important for performance to perform parallel I/O (you need a filesystem supporting it however... I am aware of IBM GPFS), I would avoid to write a custom TIFF driver with MPI_IO.

Instead the typical solution is to gather (MPI_Gather()) the image parts on the process with rank==0 and let it only save the tiff file.

Comment: Just a silly thought: Maybe write a file for each chunk of the image and then have a postbuild step which simply merges the chunks? Indeed, this approach might require a customized TIFF library (which is what the OP is probably using anyway)...

Comment: not silly at all :) MPI is not always the best tool for anything. However I expect the followup being "how to collect the image" - and here MPI datatypes can be of great help - it depends on the distribution of the image. The library mentioned by the OP is just [libtiff](http://www.unix.com/man-page/all/3tiff/TIFFSetDirectory/).

Comment: That's true :) Still, passing chunks around might be slow... Or does MPI know how to pass pointers to locations in memory? Does MPI use a shared memory model?

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. I am dealing with huge images and I need to write them in parallel. The traditional way of writing, as you suggested, using the master node to write, is the thing that I will do, but I kinda hope that there would be any other solution for parallel I/O. I have tried to write my own custom TIFF driver with MPI_IO but I needed to rewrite a huge part of the library. Is there any other open source solution for parallel libtiff. It is really hard to believe that nobody tried to write a parallel IO for the tiff library.

Comment: well, once you have a working version with MPI_Gather() and [MPI datatypes](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.2/mpi22-report/node71.htm) you are close to use MPI-IO, where you need datatypes as well. I don't know about TIFF format - I would be able to write easily an uncompressed [PPM](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html) file wth MPI_IO. I guess the main problem would be to deal with compression eventually for TIFF too.

Comment: @Mihai: no shared memory with MPI. However without an explicit parallel filesystem (that is, with *basic* NFS) using MPI-IO is just worthless. IO is slower than communicating *usually*.